# How to initialize stepper motor?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor

Friends,

My robot is actuated by a stepper motor, so I can keep track of positions changes while the power is on. But how can I initialize the robot at power on ? Do I need a sensor ?
This is in case the position has been moved while the power was off.

Here is a [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LStomTxwKcU) showing my robot.

Comment: I have edited your question slightly so that it makes more sense. I hope you don't mind. Hopefully it will improve the quality of the answers you receive here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Fit an absolute encoder to the motor so that you always know its position, even if it gets moved while the power is off.
2. At power on, perform a referencing procedure. Many milling machines do this. They will drive the motors until they hit an end stop or reference switch or sensor, at which point they know exactly where they are.

### Added:

To decide on your solution, you first need to think about what accuracy you require. Having seen the video, my guess would be that it doesn't need to be super accurate. Whatever sensor you choose has to be able to measure the motor's position to the accuracy you require.

You also need to decide if the motor needs to be able to rotate more than 360º. If it's less than 360º then you can just use an end-stop with a microswitch.

[image: Microswitch]

Screw the switch down to the base of your robot using the two handy screw holes. And attach a piece of wood on the moving part of the robot so that it bumps into the switch. Whenever the robot resets, it can simply drive slowly round until it detects the switch was pressed, and then it knows exactly where it is.

Comment: where should I put the switch or sensor ? what kind of sensor do I need ?

Comment: @RickAnt - I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

All disk drives with stepper motor actuators (when I knew this technology well)  used a  metal flag and optical interrupter for sensing the home position on power up or any reset condition.  ( tear apart a CD or floppy)

Many methods of sensing "home" or "end stop" 
  Consider one such optical sensor [here](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CD4QFjAD&url=http://www.everlight.com/datasheets/ITR8307.pdf&ei=ycWST-TtGoLH6QGHr_SzBA&usg=AFQjCNHMBScZflOjJ_ttkfjhNxbTCrdH0w&sig2=pvVF1YctPshyO5z1VQUpTQ) uses gap and acts like transistor so requires skill to use like tx/rx signal detector, but low cost.

Answer (score 0):

Errr, I'm so sick with that micro-switch idea !

If your using a microcontroller then go ahead a buy($$$) a hall effect sensors which
have a SPI interface. They are quite fancy, easy to interface and rich in precision.

http://www.melexis.com/Hall-Effect-Sensor-ICs/Triaxis%C2%AE-Hall-ICs/MLX90363-759.aspx

[note :- please note that I'm not work for melexix ,you could chose any other vendor
with SPI enabled if you wish].

Comment: They are lovely sensors. But it seems strange to spend money on an absolute sensor when you have a stepper motor. These make more sense with a DC motor and PIC controller.

Comment: There is a application note on Microchip web site:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/Sensorless%20BLDC%2000901a.pdf  They are completely sensor less methods.But it's for Y and Delta burshless.Same method, sensing the back emf can be applied to stepper too.

Comment: something like : http://academic.csuohio.edu/embedded/Publications/Thesis/Chirayu_thesis.pdf never tested by me BTW

Comment: Yes, I have seen stepper drivers which can detect stall. Can't remember where though.